# Openlayer-3 : Draw a polyline with GPS coordinates

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

For my company, I must develop a function who draw a path with GPS coordinates. Indeed, my company use GPS to track runners during multiple race.

So, i tried many differents way to draw my polyline, my last version is:

```
                _public.drawPolyline = function(pool, id, points, color, opacity, weight) {
            try {
                var l = points.length;
                var latlngs = [];
                var j=1;
                for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                    latlngs[i] = new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([points[i].longitude, points[i].latitude], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'));
                };

                var style = new ol.style.Style({
                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                        color: color,
                        width: weight,
                        opacity: opacity,
                        radius: 6
                    })
                });
                //Check if pool exists, else create it
                if (!_private._polyline.containsKey(pool)) {
                    _private._polyline.put(pool, new jQuery.Hashtable())
                }
                var currentPool = _private._polyline.get(pool);
                //Check if line exists, if yes, update path
                if (currentPool.containsKey(id)) {
                    var vectorLayer = currentPool.get(id).layer;
                    vectorLayer.setVisible(true);
                } else {              
                    var linefeature = new ol.source.Vector('Path', {styleMap: style});
                    var comp = new ol.geom.LineString(latlngs);
                    var featurecomp = new ol.Feature({
                        name: "Comp",
                        geometry: comp
                    });
                    var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
                        title: pool,
                        visible: true,
                        source: linefeature
                    });
                    linefeature.addFeatures(featurecomp);
                    currentPool.put(id, linefeature);
                    currentPool.put(id, { "type": "Path", "url": id, "layer": vector });
                    var vectorLayer = currentPool.get(id).layer;
                    vectorLayer.setVisible(true);
                }
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e.message);
            }
        }
```

So, I wanted to draw a Polyline with a function with differents parameters:
  - pool: an Hashtable storing my polyline
  - id: not important
  - points: Contain an array of objects (
`{"location":[{"id":1854703,"latitude":42.831,"longitude":0.30087,"altitude":0,"hpl":0,"vpl":0,"speed":4,"direction":258,"date":"2012-08-25 03:43:23","device_id":786,"datereceived":"2012-08-25 03:43:23"}`).

According to my test server, I have no error in my logs, but, I still don't have a polyline drawed.

If someone could help me with this, it would be great.

Regards, Brz.

Comment: your GPS coords are projected on Lon Lat ..... means EPSG:4326. Is your map projected in  EPSG:4326???? If not, you have to make sure gps layer and your map are projected in the same projection.

Comment: Hi Pavlos, I think my coordinates aren't the problem, we use this transform between 'EPSG:4326' and 'EPSG:3857' in all our functions. But, i'll try to see if I can change these.

Comment: If you reproject the coords then there shouldnt be any problem. But just double check if your gps features have the right coords (EPSG:3857)

Comment: Hi Pavlos. So, I verified according to my previous transform, and, the coordinates from my current transform are good. For example, I used to set markers: `var coord_transform = new ol.proj.transform(coord, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');`. My markers are where they must be. I don't think the transform is the problem here :/

Comment: If your map is projected in 3857 then the tranformation code you provide should be `var coord_transform = new ol.proj.transform(coord, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');`

Comment: Hi Pavlos, If i change for var coord_transform = new ol.proj.transform(coord, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');, my map isn't visible. I just have a blank page.

Comment: Do you know what is your map projection???? It would be wise to provide a fiddle in order to demonstrate your case. Unless you do that we can only guess what may be your problem

Comment: Hi Pavlos, it looks like my map use "EPSG:4326" as projection.

Comment: If you map is projected in EPSG:4326 then there is no need to transform your gps coords as you allready get them in 4326. You do tranform them to 3857 and so may not get displayed.

Comment: Hi Pavlos, so, i tried without my transform `latlngs[i] = new ol.geom.Point([points[i].longitude, points[i].latitude]);`. But, I still haven't my polyline drawn on my map :/

Comment: Unless you provide a fiddle we can't really help you.

Comment: Hmmm, what mean "fiddle"?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ build a demo of your not working code so we can examine your case and uidentify the problem. Here is a fiddle with the official ol3 gpx example ---> http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/da2mf5oh/

Comment: Hi Pavlos, I tried to build a working demo, but, I have so much different script than I don't know how to make them work on jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to create LineString points as below

```
points.push(ol.proj.transform([xx,yy],'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'));
```

Demo Link https://plnkr.co/edit/WqWoFzjQdPDRkAjeXOGn?p=preview

**Edits**

```
            var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({});
            var vectorSourcePoint = new ol.source.Vector({});
            var style = new ol.style.Style({
            image: new ol.style.Circle({
                radius: 4,
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: color
                }),
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: color,
                    width: weight,
                    opacity: opacity
                })
            })
        });
        var l = points.length;
        var latlngs = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            latlngs.push(ol.proj.transform([points[i].longitude, points[i].latitude],'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'));

            //below 3 lines of code creates point geometry. I think you don't need this
            var point = new ol.geom.Point([points[i].longitude, points[i].latitude]).transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
            var fea = new ol.Feature({geometry:point});
            vectorSourcePoint.addFeature(fea);
        };

        //below lines of code creates polyline. You are missing these lines.
        var thing = new ol.geom.MultiLineString([points]);
        var featurething = new ol.Feature({
            name: "Thing",
            geometry: thing
        });
        vectorSource.addFeature( featurething );
```